# Count в условии для Case

Tags: oracle

(Это не настоящие названия таблиц и колонок, исходный запрос слишком громоздкий)

Имеется 3 связанных таблицы `A`,`B` и `C`. Мне нужно написать запрос, который, помимо прочего, выводит колонку, содержание которой определяется условием: если к `A.id` относится 1 запись из `C`, то `C.value1`, иначе `B.value2` (оба значения имеют одинаковый тип данных).

Посчитать количество строк, относящихся к `A.id`, мне удалось:

```
SELECT A.id, count(C.id) AS counts
FROM A inner join B ON A.col1 = B.id
INNER JOIN C ON B.col2 = C.col3
GROUP BY A.id
```

но попытка сделать что-то подобное:

```
SELECT A.id, count(C.id) AS counts,
CASE WHEN count(C.id) = 1 THEN C.value1 ELSE B.value2 END AS value
FROM A inner join B ON A.col1 = B.id
INNER JOIN C ON B.col2 = C.col3
GROUP BY A.id
```

Выдаёт `ORA-979: not a GROUP BY expression`.

Что нужно скорректировать, чтобы не пришлось делать подзапрос в условии `CASE`?

Answer (score 1):

Case добавить в group by

```
SELECT A.id, count(C.id) AS counts,
CASE WHEN count(C.id) = 1 THEN C.value1 ELSE B.value2 END AS value
FROM A inner join B ON A.col1 = B.id
INNER JOIN C ON B.col2 = C.col3
GROUP BY A.id,
CASE WHEN count(C.id) = 1 THEN C.value1 ELSE B.value2 END
```

Answer (score 1):

Если использовать предложенный

```
SELECT A.id, count(C.id) AS counts,
CASE WHEN count(C.id) = 1 THEN C.value1 ELSE B.value2 END AS value
FROM A inner join B ON A.col1 = B.id
INNER JOIN C ON B.col2 = C.col3
GROUP BY A.id,
CASE WHEN count(C.id) = 1 THEN C.value1 ELSE B.value2 END
```

Получите ORA-00934: You tried to execute a SQL statement that included one of the group functions (ie: MIN Function, MAX Function, SUM Function, COUNT Function) in either the WHERE clause or the GROUP BY clause.

Поэтому, как вариант, вынести в подзапрос, но тогда вы получаете count  в разрезе C.value1 и B.value2:

```
select T.*, CASE WHEN T.counts = 1 THEN T.value1 ELSE T.value2 END AS value
from (
  SELECT A.id, C.value1, B.value2, count(C.id) AS counts
  FROM A inner join B ON A.col1 = B.id
  INNER JOIN C ON B.col2 = C.col3
  GROUP BY A.id, C.value1, B.value2) T
```